# How to delete the any particular chats from the chat application android firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an application where i have implemented the chats in my application. So i want to know that how can i delete a whole chat like suppose I have sent a message to someone or someone sent a message to me so how can i delete that particular chat

this is the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsOFR.jpg)

in the image above are tha chats with whom i have interacted. so if i want to delete any chat out of these how can i do that??

this is the my firebase data

[image]

Comment: What is the exact node in this structure that you want to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [delete a node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#delete_data) from the database you call `removeValue()` on a `DatabaseReference` to that node.

So you can create the entire `Chats` node with:

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
root.child("Chats").removeValue();
```

To delete a lower-level node, you can specify the entire path to that node:

```
root.child("Chats/hI151.../messages").removeValue();
```

You will need to know/specify the entire `hI151...` value in this code.